# Identificar origem de locks do banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft

bom dia!

Em meu servidor, possuo o SqlServer 2008R2 Express.

Estou tendo problemas de lock no banco de dados, porém, não estou conseguindo identificar qual processo ou qual aplicação pode estar causando estes locks.
Já procurei no Visualizador de Evento do Windows e não consegui identificar nada que ajudasse.

No SQLServer aparecem os processos na situação "Suspended" e isso fica prendendo novas consultas.

Vocês indicam alguma ferramenta para auxiliar na procura da causa destes locks, ou, quais são os procedimentos que eu devo realizar para tentar identificar?

Comment: pode usar o "*SQL Server Profiler*" e criar um *Trace*, tem uma opção para visualizar *deadlocks*

Answer (score 1):

Fernando, você pode utilizar o procedimento [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) para atividades de monitoramento, inclusive auxiliar na detecção da origem do lock.

Sugestão de leitura:

- [Different techniques to identify blocking in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2732/different-techniques-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/)
- [Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224453/inf-understanding-and-resolving-sql-server-blocking-problems)

Comment: Olá José! obrigado pela sua resposta, foi de grande ajuda os artigos que você indicou.

Comment: Fernando, os dois artigos são completos; o primeiro é didático; o segundo, embora _árido_, também contém informações úteis.